# Como retirar a barra branca do background?

Tags: html, css

[image: parte de baixo]

**meu html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ensintech</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-mobile.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <nav id="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="adm" placeholder href="#">Área administrativa / Docente</a></li>
                            <li><a class="aluno" href="#">Área do Aluno</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>

            </div>  
            <img id="logotipo" src="img/ensintech.png" alt="Logotipo">
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro">
                <img src="img/Egrande.png" id="centro">
                <p style="font-size:32px">
                    Acesso Aluno
                </p>
                <p id="subtitulo">
                    Digite seus dados de login para acessar o sistema
                </p>
                <form action="act_login.cfm" method="post" target="escondido">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control " id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Senha">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <button id="entrar" type="submit" class="form-control">Entrar </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <center><p class="copyright">&copy; 2018 - Ensintech - Todos os direitos reservados</p></center>
        <div id="rodape"></div>     
        <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Meu css**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body, html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    }
    body{
        font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
        background:url(../img/Testing-banner2.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;  
        display:block;
        font-size:16px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    header{
        width:125%;
        height:121px;
        background-color: #693;
        border-bottom: 6px solid #487f1e; 
    }
    header #logotipo {
        margin-left: 111px;
        display:none;
        margin-top: -95px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .row {
        margin-right: -3px;
        margin-left: -15px;
    }
    #centro {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 35%;
    }
    #menu ul{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        margin-left: 12px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        background-color: #693;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    #menu ul li a {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 2px 10px;
        display:block;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #693;
    }
    a.adm{
        margin-bottom: 11px;
        margin-top: -9px;
        margin-left: 72px;
    }
    a.aluno{
        margin-bottom: 11px;
        margin-top: 22px;
        margin-left: 130px;
    }

    .container p {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -595px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    form {
        margin-left:-450px;
    }
    #email {
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    #password {

        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 0;

    }
    #entrar{
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: -450px;
    }
    p.copyright {
        color: #666;
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-top: 22px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está dizendo a barra branca embaixo? Isso não é uma barra branca, é o resto do seu body. Provavelmente sobrou espaço porque esse conteúdo com imagem tem uma altura fixa. Você precisa deixar a imagem responsiva ou então definir a altura do conteúdo com a medida `100vh`.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa que está limitando o tamanho do body. Coloque o seu HTML e o CSS completo que fica mais fácil para te responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinha alguns erros no seu CSS.

Primeiro não se deve usar o Body antes do HTML

```
 body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

Segundo seu Header estava maior que o Body, isso estava buggando o layout...

```
 header{
    width:125%; /* bug no layout use apenas 100% */
    height:121px;
    background-color: #693;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #487f1e; 
}
```

Ajuste que fiz no Body para o Background ficar na tela inteira

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/500/500);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Vaja como ficou completo:

> **OBS:** Tive que retirar o **`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {}`** para vc poder visualisar aqui no site. *Mas coloque a regra de volta no seu arquivo ok.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />



    <style>
   
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    }
    body {
        background-image: url(http://placecage.com/500/500);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
        display: block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 121px;
        background-color: #693;
        border-bottom: 6px solid #487f1e;
    }
    header #logotipo {
        margin-left: 111px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: -95px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .row {
        margin-right: -3px;
        margin-left: -15px;
    }
    #centro {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 35%;
    }
    #menu ul {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        margin-left: 12px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        background-color: #693;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    #menu ul li a {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 2px 10px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #693;
    }
    a.adm {
        margin-bottom: 11px;
        margin-top: -9px;
        margin-left: 72px;
    }
    a.aluno {
        margin-bottom: 11px;
        margin-top: 22px;
        margin-left: 130px;
    }

    .container p {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -595px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    form {
        margin-left: -450px;
    }
    #email {
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    #password {

        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    #entrar {
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: -450px;
    }
    p.copyright {
        color: #666;
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-top: 22px;
    }

    </style>

</head>

<body>



    <header>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <nav id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a class="adm" placeholder href="#">Área administrativa / Docente</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="aluno" href="#">Área do Aluno</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

        </div>
        <img id="logotipo" src="img/ensintech.png" alt="Logotipo">
    </header>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro">
            <img src="img/Egrande.png" id="centro">
            <p style="font-size:32px">
                Acesso Aluno
            </p>
            <p id="subtitulo">
                Digite seus dados de login para acessar o sistema
            </p>
            <form action="act_login.cfm" method="post" target="escondido">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control " id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Senha">
                </div>
            </form>
            <button id="entrar" type="submit" class="form-control">Entrar </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <center>
        <p class="copyright">&copy; 2018 - Ensintech - Todos os direitos reservados</p>
    </center>

    <div id="rodape"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado o problema do background funcionou, mas agora estou em duvida uma coisa porque, consertando isso achei que resolveria o problema de estar conseguindo mexer a tela para o lado. Segue a imagem a seguir: http://prntscr.com/hzmbu3

Comment: @FranciscoCarlosCarvalhoJr coloca no body "overflow-x:hidden" que deve resolver. Qq coisa me fala

Comment: não funcionou =/

Comment: @FranciscoCarlosCarvalhoJr eu não consegui reproduzir esse erro aqui pelo browser, mas acho que deve ser por causa dessas `margin-left: -450px;` que vc está usando, tente tira-las e testa.